# How to show a UIViewController in a iOS Titanium module?

Tags: ios, uiview, module, titanium-mobile, titanium-modules

I want to push/show a view controller from iOS Titanium module.

I tried the below code

```objecitve-c
- (id) OnMainUI {ENSURE_UI_THREAD(OnMainUI, nil);
   UIViewController *controller = [INITIALIZATION OF CONTROLLER];
   [[TiApp app] showModalController: controller animated: YES];
}
```

but it shows error TiApp not found.

and how to create UIView as described in the below URL
http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/138149/how-to-show-a-uiviewcontroller-in-a-ios-titanium-module

Kindly help to show a view from iOS Titanium module.

Comment: did you import all required libraries?

Comment: in Module.h file #import "TiModule.h"
and Module.m file 
#import "TiBase.h"
#import "TiHost.h"
#import "TiUtils.h"
What else to import?

It shows "Use of undeclared identifier 'TiApp'"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to import TiApp.h to your source

```
#import "TiApp.h"
```

//The other header files that is commonly used for module developement:

```
#import "TiProxy.h"
#import "TiUtils.h"
#import "TiColor.h"
```